# How to link buttons to internal Webview with different sites?

Tags: android, android-webview

I am writing this cause I was searching for days to get an answer on my question but I didn't find any answers . . .

I am like for a month using android studio and everything is going perfect but . . . I cant find an solution to something, I added some buttons into a layout and I wat that when I click on the button it redirects me to my Webview. I want to use only one Webview and every time when I click one  of the buttons it had to go to another website in the Webview. I tried many of things I found on SO but couldn't find the right answer.

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call WebView's loadUrl() method inside the listeners of your buttons:

```
my_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

          my_webView.loadUrl("www.some_url.com");

    }
});
```

You can always change your webview's url to what you need depending on the button you clicked.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote that with an app I downloaded to my phone, and everytime I try to format the code is always a big trouble. Went to the computer and fixed it xD

Comment: Thanks for your question! I will try it in a few hours and reply if it worked, and if it worked, I will mark your answer as the solution!

Comment: No.. sorry.. it didn't work :/ maybe cause my webview is in another activity??

Comment: I don't know if it's on another activity, I hadn't seen your entire code when I wrote that answer. You may need to pass the context of your original class to the class where you want to change the WebView, so you'll be able to do something like `context.myWebView.loadUrl("url");`. Anyway you'll have to use the `context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()){...}` and set the url inside this runnable.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it.. I had to do this in the webview activity:
public class Webview extends Activity {

Sorry  had the wrong activity at the end!